# SSRS Dynamic Columns Display

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Using SQL 2008R2

I have a need to create a SSRS report where the user can specify the Columns returned AND the order in which they are returned.  Dynamic data and ordering.

Example:
Available Columns A,B,C,D,E

User specifies they want to see:  C,D,A

No issue on the data side, I'm using a stored procedure and can handle this no issue.

On the SSR side, I've seen similar question mention using a "matrix".
However I'm looking for opinions on the best approach on how to handle this on the SSRS Side.   What is the best way to handle dynamic number of returned columns and dynamic ordering of columns..

Comment: Can you provide with some sample data?

Comment: This is not a road you want to go down with SSRS, consider using SSAS for such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been mentioned, SSRS is not the way to go for this.

If the order of the columns were not customizable then you could handle column visibility using SSRS expressions but presenting the columns in a dynamic order is not easy in SSRS.

For that kind of thing you could use Excel's pivot table functionality, use a 3rd party .NET solution like MVC or build some home-grown ASP.net solution.

Comment: For the column customization, I was thinking of simply passing up the requested columns to the Stored Proc, Then at the end of the procedure, once all data has been processed and is in a Temp Table.  I would use Dynamic SQL to return ONLY the requested column....in their specified order.   So really what I was looking for is more of a I need to display data on a report (grid - like?) but don't necessarily know which field would be in which column.  I just didn't want to say column1 on a grid/matrix is "Gender".   I'd prefer it not really care can display whatever came down in that position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. In SSRS, create parameters ColumnA and ColumnB

2. Create your dataset---don't directly type your query, use expression (the fx button)
   [image]
3. In the expression, you can write your query like this:
   ="SELECT " + Parameters!ColumnA.Value + "," + Parameters!ColumnA.Value + " FROM Table"

You can solve your dynamic ORDER BY problem by the same way.

Comment: More tips worth trying (not sure if it would work though): you can try to make the Column parameter accept multiple value. You can set the available value of the parameter to be the columns' name in that table, or get it from a query to make it more dynamic. Then use JOIN function in you query expression to concatenate them. Like this: JOIN(Parameters!Column.Value, ",")    Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm doing that pretty much now!  So my cell expression is something like:   
     =Fields(Split(Parameters!pRequestedColumns.Value,",")(0)).Value  

Where (0) is the ordinal position of the requested columns.

My issue at the moment is that If i have if i requested n number of columns then if i have maximum potential columns (lets say 10) set up like above, if I only request 3 of possible 10, then my column 4 to 10 show as "#error".

I'm trying to come up with a column visibility expression that will hide the column if not requested, but I can't figure it out at the moment.

Comment: @JTSOne I would also try to work on the column visibility setting. Actually, why don't you just put all the columns into the SELECT statement in your dataset, and set column visibility based on user's selection in the parameter? Unless you're trying to eliminate the number of columns for better performance.

Comment: Not for performance.   The issue is not just which columns I want to return dynamically but also their presentation order.   I may have the solution by adding an expression to the tablix columns visibility.  For example In the 2nd column I put this expression in the column visibility:  =IIF((2 <= Split(Parameters!pRequestedColumns.Value,",").length), FALSE, TRUE)  So basically it says "If this column (second) ordinal number is less than or equal to the number of requested columns, show it.   So I'm relating the two.   Seems to work...at the moment.